# FullSimplify gives erroneous answer

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

FullSimplify gives a wrong expression when simplifying Hypergeometric functions:

```
f = Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 - n, -n, 1 - 2 n, -4 a];
g = FullSimplify[f];
```

The difference between the two expressions does not vanish:

```
Simplify[(f - g) /. {n -> 3, a -> 1}]
9-4 Sqrt[5]
```

Any workarounds and/or warnings of this unexpected behavior?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't ask any question.

Comment: Thanks, but I seem to get the wrong answer using FunctionExpand as well. I still get 9-4 Sqrt(5)

Comment: @corey979 Give Henry a break, he is a new contributor. Henry, please rephrase your post as a question. e.g. Is there a workaround? or, I am running Mathematica version x on platform y, can this be reproduced on other versions / platforms?

Comment: The expressions seem to be equal except on `FunctionSingularities[f, {n, a}]` -- not sure that counts as a problem: "The output is generically equivalent to the input" per the docs for `FullSimplify`. Also see "Possible Issues" in the docs.

Comment: In support of @MichaelE2 comment, look at `Column[Plot3D[#, {a, -1, 10}, {n, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 75, MaxRecursion -> 5, ClippingStyle -> None, ImageSize -> Medium, WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@ {f, g, f - g}]`

Comment: Also, `Limit[f - g, {a -> 1, n -> 3}]` evaluates to `0`